# How can I find specific elements in a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a data set file that has 3 columns in it.

```
0 0 1
1 0 0
0 1 0
```

I have the loaded the data file into MATLAB and now I want to check for which column the output "1" is present.

The name of the file is: out.data

In the first row "1" is present in the 3rd column. How do I write it in matlab?

Comment: Why don't you consult MATLAB Help? It is very well written with lots of examples!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
output = [0 0 1 ; 1 0 0 ; 0 1 0];

[~,index] = max(output, [], 2)
index =
     3
     1
     2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do

```
[junk,column_index] = max(data,[],2);
```

then `column_index` corresponds the first column in each row that has the 1 (assuming the data is well behaved).

Answer (score 0):

This is without actually checking it (don't have matlab available right now), but might work:

```
>> b = a';
>> rem(find(b(:) == 1),3) + 1
```